# Install from github - Developing a package

Tags: r

I am building a package in R for limited distribution within my team. The package uses functions from a few other CRAN packages. However, for one of the packages I would like to install the development version of the package from github.

I am using the `@import` tag in my ROxygen comments and also providing the package name in my description file, under Imports)
However, how do I specify that this particular package needs to be installed from github, when a user installs my package?

I tried a few different ways but none of them seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a local repository -- and the [drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html) package makes it

- trivially easy to create and host a repo for R packages on GitHub
- possible to host non-CRAN packages there
- possible to host dev versions of your (and others !!) packages there
- easy to stay in the `install.packages()` and `update.packages()` flow

We use [drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html) at work for similar reasons, and I combine our local drat repo with two development drat repos (which are public) and CRAN.